Are these internal walls load bearing?
Can someone please help acertain whether the walls highlighted in red are load bearing? One of them feels quite solid when I am knocking on it but I am not sure how to tell. The one highlighted in yellow is also very solid feeling but it shows as a thin wall on the blueprints so not sure..
Thanks for your help



The chance that none of the marked walls is load-bearing is close to zero.  You are better off asking "Which of these walls is load bearing?" To figure that out you will need to do some work.  The link in the previous comment is good.

@jay613, most modern homes of typical size have full-span roof trusses. Only very large or architecturally complicated designs tend to have interior bearing. I'd say it's close to zero chance that any of those walls are bearing, particularly because they don't have common alignment and there are no correlating beams in the drawing. There's not enough information here to know, though.

@isherwood I am assuming (never wise I know) the first diagram with the tree is downstairs and the second with the bedrooms above it.  I don't think full span beams on lower floors are so standard without an open plan to justify it?   Looks like about 28 feet I think.

That's a fair point. I think you're probably right.
